# Are parallel branches the best way to manage similar projects which share code?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-stash, git-fork

I have two projects (Product-line A and Product-line B) which share about 90% of the same code. I want to migrate both projects to GitHub.

Should I use the common code as the master branch and create a new branches for product-line A and product-line B? Would there be any disadvantage to having two parallel branches that I have no intention of merging? The code will need to be used by multiple users from multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would there be any disadvantage to having two parallel branches that I have no intention of merging?

No disadvantages: branches aren't always meant to be merged.

The only issue with that model is to clearly differentiate commits/changes done on the common code from ones done on PA or PB: changing files in PA or PB alone is not enough: you need to check if those changes are part or not of the common code.

Answer (score 1):

if there's a common base, shouldn't it be extracted to a library/framework?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11999820)

Comment: He asked for the best way to manage 2 projecta with common code base, this is my answer as I believe it's the best way instead of 2 branches

Comment: Changes to the code base will be needed as both projects are still in development. I'm not convinced that a library would be the best approach.

Comment: @AlBlue: I agree with pedro, this is a suggestion in the form of a question, and is not actually asking for clarification from the OP.

Comment: @pedrorijo91: it's probably a good idea to explain the answer a bit better